# How can I bind a query with a join to a GridView, with a Linq datasource with a business layer and data access layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have two tables that I'd like to join together display in a GridView

```
foo
fooID  fooName barID
1      Alice   2
2      Bob     1
3      Charlie 1

bar
barID  barTitle
1      Developer
2      Project Manager
```

(relationships and constraints have been defined in the database)

I've got a GridView for `foo` that outputs like this

```
Name    Title
Alice   2
Bob     1
Charlie 1
```

But I'd like see the following

```
Name    Title
Alice   Project Manager
Bob     Developer
Charlie Developer
```

Clearly, my SQL would look like:

```
select fooName as Name, barTitle as Title
from foo join bar on foo.barid = bar.barid
```

Buried deep in my code I have the following:

FooDAL.cs

```
// ...
namespace ourDAL{
// ...
public class fooDAL : ICRUD <foo>, IDisposable //ICRUD is just an interface
{
// ...
  ourPoco context; // ourPoco was auto generated by a template from our  
                   // database and an EDMX file.

  public fooDAL()
  {
      context = new ourPoco;
  }
// ...
    public IList<Cfoo> FindAll()
    {
        return (from c in context.foo
                select c).ToList<foo>();
    }
// ...
```

**I think in here I should be able to construct a Join in Linq, but I'm not sure how to do that. How can I mod the Linq code to handle the join?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
select  a.fooName as Name, b.barTitle as Title from foo a inner join bar b
on a.barid= b.barid
```

also in your grid you need to change from

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="BarID" HeaderText="Title" />
```

to

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
```

The equivalent LINQ query would be:

```
var a = (from p in foo 
            join q in bar 
            on p.barid equals q.barid 
            select new { Name= p.fooName , Title = q.barTitle }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes indeed, I included basically the same query in my question. How would I implement that in Linq or use the other method suggested by my co-worker?

Comment: No Joy... I get the following error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ourEntities.foo>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: ok try this: select new foo{ Name= p.fooName , Title = q.barTitle }).ToList();

Comment: name and title must be the properties of the foo class